# Initializing object to an empty list from a reference parameter

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

```
class ListOfGifts
{
   private:
       Gift list[50];
       int count = 0;

   public:
       void suggest(ListOfGifts& affordable, float dollarLimit) const
       {
            // how do I initialize affordable to an empty list without a constructor
       }

}
```

Trying to initialize a list from a parameter that is a reference. How can I do this?

Comment: How about `affordable.count=0;`?

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `std::array`:

```
class ListOfGifts
{
   private:
       std::array<Gift, 50> list;
       int count = 0;

   public:
       void suggest(ListOfGifts& affordable, float dollarLimit) const
       {
            affordable.list = std::array<Gift, 50>{};
       }

}
```

FYI, C++ is literally *built* on constructors. They will come up eventually, and they're actually quite helpful.